# Fiware IDM server issue

Tags: fiware, fiware-wilma, fiware-keyrock

I am using Fiware IDM version 6.2 and i have issues with keystone server (running on port 5000)..

Keystone is working fine until server is not used for some amount of time (around 1 hour) after that first call that arrive ( in my case from pep-proxy checking auth token) it simply enter into unresponsive mode, meaning it does not send anything back. When i cancel request and send it again it start working normal.

I would like to know if there is something on my part that i missed or failed to check.

I am using docker to run Fiware IDm enviroment.

Picture of logs

[image]

Comment: What GE's are you using? Keyrock with Wilma? Keyrock with Steelskin?

Comment: Keyrock with Wilma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an old version both Keyrock and Wilma. Currently, both of them are in version 7.5.1. Please take a look on Hub Docker (https://hub.docker.com/u/fiware). Nevertheless, the issue that you mention is due to security management. The admin tokens expire after 1h, therefore you need to obtain a new one to continue working with it.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding this issue, at moment due to some demand I cannot swap versions.